# How long to keep duck eggs

Tags: eggs, duck

Came home from offshore an still have duck eggs in fridge there dated 28 march 2018 is it ok to eat them now?

Comment: Crack them open and smell them ?

Comment: In the absence of good information on Duck Eggs you might review this answer about Chicken Eggs. https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7663/how-long-can-i-keep-eggs-in-the-refrigerator/7665 and/or https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/32859/6279